# What is the general way to launch appropriate amount of reduction kernels?

Tags: cuda

As I have read from NVIDIA's instruction in this link `http://www.cuvilib.com/Reduction.pdf`, for arrays bigger than `blockSize`, I should launch multiple reduction kernels to achieve global synchronization. What is the general way to determine how many times I should launch the reduction kernel? I tried as below but I need to Malloc 2 additional pointers, which takes a lot of processing times.

My job is to Reduce the array `d_logLuminance` into one minimum value `min_logLum`

```
void your_histogram_and_prefixsum(const float* const d_logLuminance,
                              float &min_logLum,
                              const size_t numRows,
                              const size_t numCols)
{
const dim3 blockSize(512);
unsigned int pixel = numRows*numCols;
const dim3 gridSize(pixel/blockSize.x+1);

//Reduction kernels to find max and min value
float *d_tempMin, *d_min;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**) &d_tempMin, sizeof(float)*pixel));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**) &d_min, sizeof(float)*pixel));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_min, d_logLuminance, sizeof(float)*pixel, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));

dim3 subGrid = gridSize;
for(int reduceLevel = pixel; reduceLevel > 0; reduceLevel /= blockSize.x) {
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_tempMin, d_min, sizeof(float)*pixel, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
    reduceMin<<<subGrid,blockSize,blockSize.x*sizeof(float)>>>(d_tempMin, d_min);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
    subGrid.x = subGrid.x / blockSize.x + 1;
}

checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&min_logLum, d_min, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

std::cout<< "Min value = " << min_logLum << std::endl;

checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_tempMin));
checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_min));

}
```

And if you are curious, here is my reduction kernel:

```
__global__
void reduceMin(const float* const g_inputRange,
                 float* g_outputRange)
{
extern __shared__ float sdata[];
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;    
unsigned int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
sdata[tid] = g_inputRange[i];
__syncthreads();

for(unsigned int s = blockDim.x/2; s > 0; s >>= 1){
    if (tid < s){
        sdata[tid] = min(sdata[tid],sdata[tid+s]);
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

if(tid == 0){
  g_outputRange[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to skin the cat, but if you want to minimize kernel launches, it can always be done with at most two kernel launches.

The first kernel launch is composed of up to however many blocks correspond to the number of *threads per block* that your device supports.  Newer devices will support 1024, older devices, 512.

Each of these (at most 512 or 1024) blocks in the first kernel will participate in a grid-looping sum of all the data elements in global memory.

Each of these blocks will then do a partial reduction and write a partial result to global memory.  There will be 512 or 1024 of these partial results.

The second kernel launch will be composed of 512 or 1024 threads in a single block.  Each thread will pick up one of the partial results from global memory, and then the threads in that single block will cooperatively reduce the partial results to a single final result, and write it back to global memory.

The "grid-looping sum" is described in reduction #7 [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) as "multiple add/thread".  All of the reductions described in this document are available in the NVIDIA [reduction sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have a concern. Assume that my device supports 1024 threads per block, and we need to reduce an array that has 1024^3 elements. Doesn't that mean we need at least 3 kernel launches? First kernel launches 1024^2 blocks; Second kernel launches 1024 blocks; Third kernel launches 1 block.

Comment: No, you still need two kernel launches. I doubt you've bothered to understand my answer or even look at the link, since you've responded in just a few minutes.  The first kernel launch is *not limited in any way* in terms of the number of elements it can process.  It will **loop** cooperatively over the entire data set, even if that data set fills every last available byte in global memory.